# Как правильно отправить сообщение нескольким пользователями через Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

После авторизации заношу socket.id в массив. После события open_modal нужно отправить событие тем кто есть в массиве.

```
    // authorization event
    socket.on('auth', async data => {
      const result = await authorization(data.token);

      if (result) {
        sockets.push(socket.id);
      }
    });

    // open modal event
    socket.on('open_modal', async data => {
      if (sockets.indexOf(socket.id) !== -1) {
        // set open user item by socket id index
        socketsOpenItem.push({
          socketId: socket.id,
          openItem: data.id
        });

        // generate event for block item
        socket.emit('block_item', {itemId: data.id});

        const result = await closedEdit(data.id);
      } else {
        socket.emit('error', {
          code: 403,
          error: 'Пользователь не авторизован'
        })
      }
    });
```

Как оправить сообщение тем, кто есть в sockets ?
В соседней теме есть способ, но конкретному пользователю, можно конечно и циклом, но может есть вариант лучше ?

```
io.sockets.connected[users[message.user_id]].emit('message', message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно после авторизации добавлять юзеров в определенную комнату, а потом отправлять сообщение всей комнате. Это выглядит примерно так:

```
const roomName = 'justExample';

io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
   socket.on('auth', async data => {
      const result = await authorization(data.token);

      if (result) {
         socket.join(roomName); // добавляем в комнату
      }
    });

  socket.on('open_modal', async data => {
     io.to(roomName).emit('message', 'test message'); // отправляем собщение всем в комнате
  });
}
```

Comment: В этом случае нужно какую-то дополнительную защиту писать ? Или без сервера в комнату не попасть ?

Comment: Или зная url можно отправить туда сообщение ?

Comment: @VladimirGolub нет, управлением комнатами занимается только сервер, с клиентской части в комнату попасть нельзя.